# Mixing Spring and JAX-RS annotation

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs

I inherited a project where the original author of the project mixed JAX-RS annotations with Spring Annotations, such as below:

```
@Component
@Path("/users")
public class Api {
    @Autowired
    private UserSerivce userService;

    @Resource(name = "list")
    private List<String> someOther;

    @Get
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
       return Response.status(200).entity(userService.getUser(id)).build();
    }
}
```

I chose to continue developing the same way. But I was wondering, should I only use one or is it fine to continue develop like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of projects out there which uses JAX-RS instead of Spring controllers. Probably because the reference implementation is by the same people who drafted the specification.It is fine to continue developing like this.

You can check out this project to which I am an active contributor - https://github.com/openMF/mifosx - a platform for delivering the complete range of financial services needed for an effective financial inclusion solution.

However, you can always go the full Spring way using [Spring Boot](http://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) using [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/).